# Cloning object with closures

Tags: php, object, closures

I have the following class in PHP5.3:

```
class MyClass {
    public $a=1;
    public $hook;
    function setHook(){
        $t=$this;
        $this->hook=function() use($t){
            echo $t->a;
        };
   }
}
```

The following syntax works as expected:

```
$x = new MyClass();
$x->setHook();
call_user_func($x->hook);     // outputs 1;
```

However if I continue with this code:

```
$y = clone $x;
$y->a = 2;
call_user_func($y->hook);
```

Then it would still output 1. I understand WHY it's happens, because i've assigned a local variable which got embedded into the definition of my closure and subsequently into the "hook" property.

**Please suggest how to get around this problem**. For a class containing property with "callable" how do I clone it and make closures properly reference current object. Perhaps I can follow a different pattern. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply overwrite the `$hook` when you clone:

```
public function __clone() {
    $this->setHook();
}
```

Not sure if your example is representative of your actual code. I hope it helps.

In PHP 5.4, you can use [`Closure::bindTo`](http://php.net/closure.bindto) and `$this` directly in the closure:

```
class MyClass {
    public $a = 1;
    public $hook;

    public function setHook(){
        $this->hook=function() {
            echo $this->a;
        };
    }

    public function __clone() {
        $this->hook = $this->hook->bindTo($this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. bindTo is exactly what I needed, but don't you think you need to clone your closure before rebinding ? That might actually work well for me.

Comment: Oh, actually no cloning is necessary: From doc: "Create and return a **new** anonymous function". Thanks for a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simpliest way would be [self-encapsulation](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/selfEncapsulateField.html):

```
private function getA() { return $this->a;}

$this->hook=function(){
        echo $this->getA();
}
```

Comment: but you would be calling $x->getA() instead of $y->getA()

Comment: Updated a bit, not sure if it help, but it might :)